# Convert SQLite to Django ORM

Tags: mysql, django, sqlite, orm, django-orm

I have a query in SQLite which groups the fields by *weeks* and performs *sum* and *average* over *distance* and *time* fields in the same table:

```
select
    strftime('%W', datetime) WeekNumber,
    sum(distance) as TotalDistance, 
    sum(distance)/sum(time) as AverageSpeed
from sample_login_run
group by WeekNumber;
```

I am trying to convert this query to Django ORM and avoid using `Raw` function. I understand that I would need to use `extra` in Django ORM. That should not be a problem though. I came up this:

```
Run.objects.extra(select={'week': "strftime('%%W', datetime)"}).values(
            'week','distance').annotate(
            total_distance=Sum('distance'), average_time=F('distance') / F('time'))
```

But this is also grouping the data by `average_time` and `average_distance` field. Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Right solution for this is:

```
Run.objects.extra(select={'week': "cast(strftime('%%W', date_run) as integer)"}).values('week').annotate(
                total_distance=Sum('distance'), average_time=F('distance') / F('time'))
```

Fields passed in `values` will go under `group by` part of the query.